# Rsync - How to Include Specific Parts of File Path

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use Rsync filters to manipulate how the file structure appears at my target destination. I've read through other SE questions and consulted Google, but am still having trouble.

As an example, I have the following file structure:

```
/home/donglecow/images/123/001/image.jpg
/home/donglecow/images/123/002/image.jpg
/home/donglecow/images/456/001/image.jpg
/home/donglecow/images/456/002/image.jpg
```

When running Rsync, I want to copy this exact structure: `images/123/001/image.jpg`, omitting `/home/donglecow/`at first.

Once I have this working, I want to copy over everything under `images` recursively. The problem I'm having is that it only copies over the last directory and its contents, for example: `001/image.jpg`.

The command I'm using is: `rsync -avvvrz --exclude='/home/donglecow/' --include='images/*' /home/donglecow/images/123/001/ /home/donglecow/rsyncDestination`.

I end up with: `/home/donglecow/rsyncDestination/001/image.jpg`, but want `/home/donglecow/rsyncDestination/images/123/001/image.jpg`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--relative` (`-R`) argument. That will create the intermediate directories.

**Edit:**

If you don't want the "/home/donglecow/" you'll need to run rsync from that directory. For example:

```
cd /home/donglecow
rsync -aRvvvrz --exclude='*/images/' --include='images/*' images/123/001/ /home/donglecow/rsyncDestination
```

Comment: When I use `-R`, it's always pulling back `/home/donglecow/` regardless of my `--exclude` settings. Here is my revised command: `rsync -aRvvvrz --exclude='*/images/' --include='images/*' /home/donglecow/images/123/001/ /home/donglecow/rsyncDestination`

Comment: @Donglecow, ok I see, in that case you'll need to run rsync from /home/donglecow and use a relative path as the source. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Perfect, that's worked, thank you! It's also good to know for future reference, as this will be running from a script.